# Is it harder for a low-battery DMM to measure current in a comparison to measuring voltage and resistance?

Tags: multimeter

My DMM is doing a good job in measuring voltage and resistance but when I measure currents I get 0 readings. Is it possible that having a weaker battery affects only current measurements/ If so - why?

Comment: No, you have blown the fuse.

Comment: The DMM should operate if the battery is in it's normal operating condition. If the battery voltage is indicated as low, then no measurement should be trusted.

Comment: Are you plugging the probes into the right jacks on the DMM to measure current? Different jacks are used for current and voltage measurements. That's why DMMs have four jacks but only two are ever used at a time.

Comment: There's no lowBAT indication, of course I've moved the red probe to the mA jack and measured currents of less then 100mA, so I don't believe I've blown the fuse.

Comment: Well, you can always use the meter's own resistance test (at least I think you can using the same meter) to check the resistance between the ohmeter's current jacks. If it's infinite then you have blown a fuse.

Comment: what @EinarA said. If you measure current the circuit should be closed. First test if you have a closed circuit while measuring current.

Comment: I get 0mA even in a circuit of a 1.5V full battery and a 100Ohm resistor.

Comment: Yes, the test from @DKNguyen 's remark shows a blown fuse. thanks!

Comment: It is also possible that internal shunt resistors (used to measure current) have blown open. If *every current range* shows zero, the fuse is suspect. If at least *one current range* shows a reading, suspect blown shunt resistors instead.

Comment: @glen_geek Do you mean checking the mA range with currents of 1mA,10mA,100mA? Is it better to have blown shunt resistors? Because in my case the price of a fuse for my UNI-T is half the price of the DMM itself.

Comment: @OMGsh Fuse is far easier to replace than shunt resistors. Shunt resistors have fairly low value, are precision resistors, and are usually soldered onto a printed circuit board. Yes, 1mA, 10mA, 100ma would be suspect. A single fuse would be used for all three ranges. If you have a 10A current range, a good meter may include a separate fuse - a poor meter will have no fuse on the 10A range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have several DMMs, and most of them measure 0 on the current range because I'm clumsy and blow the current range protection fuse, then don't get around to replacing it because it's an oddball size.

Of course it's possible that you've toasted other components(*1) used for the current input. I'm never very sure whether the fuse provides complete input protection, especially in cheap meters.

Try replacing the fuse. And if you only have one meter, buy another couple of cheap ones, and dedicate one to current measurement. You'll often find situations where you want to measure several things simultaneously, and it's comforting to have a spare.

*1) The favourite to look at is the shunt resistor. Its power rating is limited so you can burn it quite easily. That's why all these warnings are printed on the DMM. ;-)